# Is the Current "Bounty System" favoring only "accurate" answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

PS : Before closing this question down as a duplicate, please read it completely.

A couple of days back, I asked [this question on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112992/android-setting-width-of-a-textview-to-left-of-either-button-1-or-button-2). I placed a bounty of **200** rep for the same (when I couldn't get any really good responses when the question was first asked).

A few minutes after I placed the bounty, I got a few answers. `2` of them being really helpful. Both the answers were really good and contained almost everything I needed. One of them was slightly better than the other. Now, I would have gladly split the bounty between the 2 answers or even could have awarded 2 separate bounties worth 200 for each of them. But I can't do that.

Now, if I award *one* answer with the bounty, it would certainly demotivate the other answerer (because he/she has also put in *at least some effort*) . And frankly, I feel bad when someone puts in some effort to help me and goes back *almost-empty-handed*. I could see the *sadness* in the comments (I can't blame them for that). A user puts in some effort and answers a question only to find out that he gets *nothing* (I had to split the rep in some way, I accepted one answer and awarded bounty to another and up-voted both)

So,  I feel the person who has *not* been awarded the bounty will be a little less motivated to answer the question the next time around. If this happens several times, he/she might stop answering questions (knowing some other *better* answer will get *all* the attention - in case of bounties).

***Wouldn't it be better to be allowed to split bounties or award bounties (worth the same value) to multiple answers?.*** Currently, I've placed another bounty worth `400` rep for the same question (SOF didn't allow *another 200* bounty). Will award it to the other answer.

PS : For people who think the bounty is too much for such a *trivial* question - **I don't know what I don't know!!** :P

Comment: Not necessarily against your suggestion, but just to play devil's advocate: Wouldn't it also unfair if (hypothetically) I post the best answer to your bounty question, and I don't get the full bounty? After all, you offered a bounty amount for the best answer, and I think I should get that promised amount if the effort I put in allows me to produce the best answer.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Maybe, but what he's suggesting is that the bounty not (or not necessarily) be offered for "the best answer", but just for useful answers, with the bounty-awarded deciding how to allocate the bounty.

Comment: Question: Is it not currently possible for a single user to award multiple bounties for different answers to the same question?  This would require the user to donate more rep, but if they're motivated by gratitude for good answers, they might be willing to do so.

Comment: @BrenBarn - You pretty much summed up what I wanted to convey :P

Comment: A side note: Don't highlight every keyword with backticks. An individual keyword is **not** "inline code". It makes the question _very_ difficult to read.